# What is the best way to make a diagonal cut around a round object?

Tags: modeling

I have a curved plane and I want to make a diagonal cut that follows it, I use this method:

1. With the loop cut tool I divide the inferior portion of the plane.
2. I use ctrl+T to triangulate the faces of each vertical section, that
   lets me generate a diagonal that follows the curve. The result looks
   like the image bellow.
3. I delete the faces and I get the result I want

[image]

But, is there a better way to do it? Something like selecting 2 vertices and generating the diagonal between them, or something like the loop cut tool but in diagonal and around curves.

I ask because I may to need to repeat this process some times with my model and maybe there is a quicker way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the cut through existing vertices, you coud start  by selecting 2 vertices on the diagonal you want followed, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, Select Next Active, followed by <kbd>J</kbd>, Connect.

[image]

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, to select continuously. <kbd>J</kbd> will connect all the vertices in their selection order.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a low-effort answer, I was just going to post it as a comment, but decided it needed a screenshot to illustrate the point.

Use [the Bisect Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/bisect.html?):
[image: Example]